# How do you add an image attachment to an AttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, ios15, attributedstring

I'm working to replace `NSAttributedString` with `AttributedString` but have been unsuccessful in getting attachments to work. The image doesn't appear in the string despite the fact I applied the attachment.

```
let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")!)
textAttachment.accessibilityLabel = "Warning"

// Original code
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)

// New code
var attributedString = AttributedString()
attributedString.attachment = textAttachment
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attributedString)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSAttributedString(attachment:)` magically creates an `NSAttributedString` with a single character (`NSAttachmentCharacter` which is U+FFFC OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) and applies the text attachment attribute in order to replace that character with the image.

With the new `AttributedString` API you'll need to manually replicate that:

```
let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")!)
textAttachment.accessibilityLabel = "Warning"

let attributedString = AttributedString("\(UnicodeScalar(NSTextAttachment.character)!)", attributes: AttributeContainer.attachment(textAttachment))

label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attributedString)
```

Here's an example that replaces a substring with an image:

```
let addString = "+"
let string = "Tap \(addString) to add a task."
let addTextAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: UIImage(systemName: "plus.square")!)

// NSAttributedString
label.attributedText = {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
    attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: addString), with: NSAttributedString(attachment: addTextAttachment))
    return attributedString
}()

// AttributedString
label.attributedText = {
    var attributedString = AttributedString(string)
    let attachmentString = AttributedString("\(UnicodeScalar(NSTextAttachment.character)!)", attributes: AttributeContainer.attachment(addTextAttachment))
    attributedString.replaceSubrange(attributedString.range(of: addString)!, with: attachmentString)
    return NSAttributedString(attributedString)
}()
```